# Nagios: check multiple services simultaneously?

Tags: nagios

I've just started using Nagios to monitor a group of broadcast transmitters. Each transmitter is defined as a host, and each aspect of the transmitter I wish to monitor (RF forward, RF reflected, power supply voltages, etc) is defined as a service. In doing so, I can get an alarm if any of these aspects are out of tolerance, and can use the performance data to graph each aspect (using pnp4nagios, in this case).

To check the transmitters' telemetry data, I wrote some scripts, one to address the unique facilities of each make/model of transmitter involved. In keeping with the way I've seen other Nagios checks work, an argument to the script allows you to select which aspect you want reported.

At first I was content with this. It worked like any more-traditional use of Nagios I'd encountered. But then I hit a snag.

Because each service check is scheduled individually, diagnosing an alarm condition can be tricky, since the various services aren't all being checked at the same time - and therefore the set of values I'm looking at is unlikely to be time-aligned. If all the service check values were from the same moment in time, it would be easier to detect correlations (since the set of values would essentially be a snapshot).

My first thought would be to deal with this by running a single instance of a single command, which would return values for multiple services. This would also seem far more efficient than opening as many connection instances as there are services to be checked. From a scripting perspective, this is easily done. But from a Nagios config perspective, I don't know how (or if?) you'd do that.

I know I could also divorce the data collection from the Nagios check, caching the telemetry values all at once periodically, and feeding Nagios values from the cache. But I don't want to introduce added delays if I can help it.

Thoughts?

Comment: After some additional reading, I'm considering submitting the service data passively. It would solve all the problems I mentioned.

But it would create a few minor new ones - now there's external processes to keep running, and it's a little outside the mainstream way of doing things (might put a future admin through a little pain to figure out how it works).

As always, I'm open to suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

> My first thought would be to deal with this by running a single instance of a single command, which would return values for multiple services. This would also seem far more efficient than opening as many connection instances as there are services to be checked. From a scripting perspective, this is easily done. But from a Nagios config perspective, I don't know how (or if?) you'd do that.

There's nothing strange about this from a Nagios perspective, because what you're essentially doing is writing your own plugin, and plugins can be as general or specific as you want them to be.

When writing your own plugin, it's good to remember:

- Your script is responsible for all failures, so make sure you handle garbage responses, failed connections and whatever other errors you predict may happen in the plugin itself, and exit with appropriate error levels.
- Since you may encounter errors you didn't expect, it probably makes sense to have the plugin write what it's doing to a log file, as well as what responses it got.
- The plugin must use exit codes to alert Nagios correctly. If you want performance data, it needs to be given in the correct syntax. See the [development guidelines](https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html).

> I'm considering submitting the service data passively. It would solve all the problems I mentioned. But it would create a few minor new ones - now there's external processes to keep running, and it's a little outside the mainstream way of doing things (might put a future admin through a little pain to figure out how it works).

I don't think this is a better solution than writing your own plugin, unless the data is coming from nodes actively pushing it out.

For example, in an IoT context, the nodes you are monitoring may actually be sending passive check results directly to the Nagios instance. In that setting, passive checks make sense, because you just want to take whatever someone else gives you and action in case no results come in (freshness).

In your case, it sounds like writing your own script would take care of both the timing issue and whatever else additional logic you want in your script, and as far as Nagios is concerned it should only run it on a schedule and watch the exit codes, then act as configured if it fails.

Comment: I actually wrote my own plugins from the start, so any/all options are available to me, it's just a matter of choosing the right one.

What's got me stuck as far as active checks, is that I don't know how I'd update multiple services simultaneously with a single run of a single command.

Example: At one point I was chasing down an problem that turned out to be an intermittent power supply issue. Voltage on one power supply would drop, and the transmitter's RF output would likewise drop - an easy diagnosis if you see both issues occurring at the same time. (1/3)

Comment: In Nagios, I have a service for RF output, and a service for power supply voltage (among others).

But these services update asynchronously. So, from Nagios, the smoking gun - both services being out of tolerance simultaneously - would be unlikely to appear.

The checks for each service call the same script, but with different arguments, causing the script to retrieve and report only the value(s) needed for the service being checked. (2/3)

Comment: Ideally, I'd call that script once, and update all the services simultaneously, providing a synchronized snapshot of all values, which is potentially much more useful than checking them one at a time over a longer period. (3/3)

Comment: Writing a plug-in that runs via crown and submits passive results works fine too.